# How to take props from mapStateToProps() and use them in the dependency parameter of useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-props, use-effect

'body' is returned in mapStateToProps(), so I have access to it in the class through props.

This is all happening inside of a wizard, and my goal with this code was to only have useEffect ran when the 'body' prop is changed.

I read that this is could be an issue connected to redux and how a new object is returned from mapStateToProps every time, so in a deep check, 'body' has in fact 'changed' according to react, even though the contents haven't. How can I fix this?

I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be awesome, but I was wondering if useDispatch could be used in this?

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchToken(sphere, body); //fetchToken & fetchLocations are inside mapDispatchToProps
    if (token) {
      fetchLocations(sphere, token);
    }
    counter++;
  }, [body]);
```

Comment: Would useSelector work here - I've read up a little on it and it seems the same as mapStateToProps, except that it returns a value.. So would I be able to do something like: 
let body = useSelector(state => state.body);
//and then use it in useEffect()

Comment: useSelectors and useDispatch are just hooks alternative to connect. You should instead use reselect library to memoize your selectors